# Using Amphp with a framework such as Magento

Tags: php, magento, amphp

I am trying to use Amphp Parallel functions with the Magento framework in a custom module.

```
try {
    $response = wait(parallelMap($items, function ($item) use ($arg1){
        $this->getCustomItems( $item, $arg1);
    }));

} catch (MultiReasonException $exception) {
    foreach ($exception->getReasons() as $reason) {
        var_dump($reason->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The issue i am having when running the above code is

```
Uncaught RuntimeException in worker with message "ObjectManager isn't initialized" and code "0"; use Amp\Parallel\Worker\TaskFailureException::getOriginalTrace() for the stack trace in the worker
```

The Magento framework is autoloaded using composer. So i have no clue as to why it can not initialize the object manager.

Answer (score 3):

Magento's dependencies are autoloaded with the autoload, but it is of no use when it is not initialized by the Magento kernel, you need to create a separate Magento API, and request that API by call back method (using CURL request) written in your vendor/autloload.php, this is how you can make use of amphp.